# How to separate key value pairs with comma in Java properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

Currently, my property file output looks like this

```
Name=Frank 
Email=frank@mail.com
```

based on the following codes

```
File prop = new File(".properties");

if (!prop.exists()) {
    prop.createNewFile();
}        

try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(prop);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(reader);
    reader.close();

    properties.setProperty("Name", name);
    properties.setProperty("Email", email);

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(prop);
    properties.store(writer, "Settings");
    writer.close();

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PropertiesTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I want it to be written in one line, with each key value pair separated by a comma. So it will look like this

```
Name=Frank, Email=frank@mail.com
```

How can I achieve this? Or is there a way to group each Name and Email key value pairs with a unique identifier? 
Basically, I want to have multiple Name and Email entries in one property file and to be able to get each of the entry.

Comment: I guess you have to split each line first by comma `,` and the by `=` symbol. Then you can store this information in a `HashMap<String, String>` for fetching the key/values.

Comment: You can't. That's not the format of a properties file. Define your own class, reading and writing in your own proprietary format. It seems you want to store structured objects in a file. You should use JSON or XML to do that. Not properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties file is not designed to do this. You should instead use CSV, JSON, YAML, XML (but probably XML is too complicated for this use case) or a database.